# Would I need a star topology with a dedicated ground plane?

Tags: pcb, layout, grounding

Some background:

I have a PCB with a bunch of relays on it. The purpose of the circuit, is to allow signals to pass through from one connector to another (db37), or to stop it - that's where the relays come in - to break the connection.

I have a 6 layer board with the following layer stack(signal, ground, signal, signal, power, signal).

I have +12V supply, +3.3V supply and +5V supply. The +12V is for a bunch of relays, and the +3.3V and +5V are for some microcontroller + other lower voltage ICs and components.

Some of these signals from the db37 connector MAY be higher current signals (3A) but with a frequency no more than 50khz. For the most part, we are looking at 10s of mA and 10Khz signals.

I'm using my power plane for the +12V.

My question is - can I just ground all my components to the ground plane directly or through a close proximity via or should be considering a star topology ?

Are star topologies only useful for situations where there is no dedicated ground plane ?

I suspect that because I have a dedicated ground, I should be able to simply just connect everything to ground. But PCB grounding is fairly new to me.

Comment: What kind of sub-circuits will you have on the board?  Will you have precision analog, RF?  Will you have switch mode power supplies?  A block diagram (or a schematic) would help answer your question.  Also, it sounds odd that a seemingly simple (?) relay board requires 6 layers.

Comment: I'll try and update my question with a block diagram later tonight or tomorrow morning. The reason for 6 layers, is that I'm confined to a tight area, and I have 41 relays per board. Since each trace is set up to handle 3A, they get rather thick. I can't route all signal paths without 4 signal layers.

Comment: No precision analog, rf or switch mode power supply on this board, but in a future version, I'd like to have some precision analog and switch mode power supply as well. But for the time being, the main focus is just the 41 relays.

Answer (score 5):

One of the advantages of star grounding is that you define the current paths for some signals.  With a ground plane the current paths are up to the electrons and the voltage potential.  You may end up causing a voltage dip or surge for one component on the board at a location where a higher surge current passes near the ground pin during, for instance, a relay activation.

It may not matter for your board, you haven't provided enough information to determine that, but the answer to your general question is:

No, a ground plane does not replace a star grounding system in all cases, and the problems a star grounding system can solve are not all resolved with a ground plane.  In fact a ground plane may exacerbate certain types of problems that a star grounding system can solve.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update my question with a block diagram  that may give you some more information. But its definitly good to know that a ground plane is not a universal solve all and that depending on the circuit/application, other methods of good grounding are required.